# OS X Time Machine

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery, time-machine, partition-recovery

So was trying to backup my time machine drive onto another disk, but I got an message about it being case sensitive. So I was playing around with Disk Utility in El-Capitan, I was on the partition tab and I dropped it down to non case sensitive hit apply. There was no confirmation, and no warning. It started erasing the drive.

I yanked out the USB Cable literally no more than a half a second after I hit apply. When I plugged it back in it was not picking up my partition. I doubt it had enough time to actually erase anything. So my question is.. It there a way to make the drive whole again? Will i get the full directory structure back?

It is a standard hdd.

I tried a handful of automated tools, and got nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have probably damaged the partition of the drive.  This is why you don't want to play around in Disk Utility, unless you REALLY know what you're doing.

Basically, ANY change you make (other than perhaps doing a drive verification) is risking a full erasure of a drive.  I work on drives for a living, and I don't play with them unless I've got a full backup.

2. It is likely recoverable.  But it's not free and it's not always easy.  You will need a scavaging-capable disk recovery app.

Here is a quick list of drive tools we use for recovery:

- DiskDrill
- DataRescue
- FileSalvage
- Boomerang*
- DiscDoctorsMac Recovery
- DiskWarrior*

*these may not work well with missing partitions.

You'll most likely need to buy one of these (I don't know what end-user pricing is, but on a pro level, most run $200+), and then run it.

Oh, and don't plug your drive in again or turn it on, until you have one of the apps to work on recovery.  You're just as likely to bugger it as to fix it.  Or you could find a company who does this and get it to them.

it's not going to be cheap/free, unless you **REALLY** get lucky.  that's one of the breaks of jacking around with partitions and directories...

For what you've described, I'd try DiskDrill...

Comment: I tried Disk Drill. The recover lost hfs partition turned up northing.

Do you think I Will I will be able to still get the directory structure back?
 
I guess I didn't think they would remove the confirmation prompt that asked you if you wanted to erase things. The old one had a clear warning prompt. They removed this In the new version of disk utility. Wish I knew what apple was smoking.